# Android: How to pass version info during ant command line build?

Tags: android, android-build

When I build an Android project in command line using Ant, I would like to update the android:versionCode and android:versionName in AndroidManifest.xml file. Are there someways I can inject version number using a property file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set version info in several ways,

1. Passing as command line parameters
2. Using a property file.

To pass as command line parameters,

```
 <target name="set-version-using-commandline-args">
    <!-- Load properties from "version.properties" file -->     
    <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml" match="android:versionCode(.*)" 
        replace='android:versionCode="${Version.Code}"'/>
    <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml" match="android:versionName(.*)" 
        replace='android:versionName="${Version.Name}"'/>       
</target>
```

Then run the ant build like this,

```
ant -DVersion.Code=100 -DVersion.Name=5.0.0.1201011 debug
```

If you want to pass the version info using a property file, use this target,

```
 <target name="set-version-using-file">
    <!-- Load properties from "version.properties" file -->             
    <property file="version.properties" />

    <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml" match="android:versionCode(.*)"
        replace='android:versionCode="${Version.Code}"'/>
    <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml" match="android:versionName(.*)"
        replace='android:versionName="${Version.Name}"'/>       
</target>
```

For detailed instruction, see this blog post. [Android: How to version command line build?](http://www.irasenthil.com/2013/01/android-how-to-version-command-line.html)

Comment: Heh.  Too bad it was your edit that bubbled this to the top where I saw it instead of when you first asked it.  It would have saved you some some time!

Comment: The above regular expression did not work for me.  The ".*" was being way too greedy and butchering the XML.  Argyle's answer is closer to what solved my problem.

Comment: Be sure that you have `android.versionCode="XXX"` and `android.versionName="XXX"` each on a separate file in the original AndroidManifest.xml or the regexp will blow up your xml syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Sure!  First, create your property file.  Say, `spiffy.properties`. Next, you're going to make use of the Android Ant build's `custom_rules.xml` file.  Create it, if you don't already have one.

Near the top of that file, add a line that looks like this:

```
<property file="spiffy.properties"/>
```

Now, add a dependency to the `-pre-build` target to call this:

```
<target name="-set-manifest-values">
  <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml">
    <regexp pattern="android:versionName=&quot;.*&quot;"/>
    <substitution expression="android:versionName=&quot;${version.name}&quot;"/>
  </replaceregexp>
  <replaceregexp file="AndroidManifest.xml">
    <regexp pattern="android:versionCode=&quot;.*&quot;"/>
      <substitution expression="android:versionCode=&quot;${build.number}&quot;"/>
  </replaceregexp>
</target>
```

With your version name and build number being specifed by `${version.name}` and `${build.number}` respectively.  Since they're properties, you can also specify them on the command-line or as part of a continuous integration setup.

Comment: I was able to get this to work, except I had to add a ? after the * to make it less greedy.  Added the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Updated AndroidManifest via Ruby, see https://gist.github.com/cybertk/24ce4d20d76f9d6a16c6

```
    File.open('AndroidManifest.xml', 'r+') do |f|
        manifest = f.read

        build = ENV['TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER'] || 0
        # Update version
        manifest = manifest.gsub(
            /android:versionCode=".*"/, "android:versionCode=\"#{build}\"")

        # Write back
        f.rewind
        f.truncate(0)
        f.write(manifest)
    end
```